# Can anyone suggest me a motivation/intuition behind Cauchy condensation test?

Tags: real-analysis

I want to know the motivation or intuition that led to the idea of cauchy condensation test.I want to visualize it.So can anyone suggest me some visualization or motivation behind the test and a reference book where I can find such intuitions behind convergence tests?

Comment: Group the terms of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n \ln^2 n}$ together to make them simpler, given that $\ln^2 n$ stays approximately constant on $[2^k,2^{k+1}]$.

Comment: What did you try to mean?Please elaborate.